# Detecting WHEN the Location Setting becomes available (ex: to log it's use time, etc)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-location

Android-Oreo has essentially broken my App and left me dead in the water..

**My Objective:** Run in the background, and react when the "Location" setting gets turned ON.

I do *not* need to actually *use* the Location - I simply need to *detect when* it becomes available.
(Unfortunately, as of Android-O, I can no longer use the providers_changed intent filter to do this).


**How can I go about doing this? Advice would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: How is this any different than your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920316/)? Why are your asking the same question again? Just because you didn't get a reply before? That is not a good reason to make a duplicate

Comment: @RemyLebeau Absolutely - I asked a similar question, multiple days passed, and now I'm re-wording my question, since my last question (days old) got absolutely no response.. How else am I supposed to get a possible answer? I've done hours upon hours of research, and am at my wits end.. Any suggestions? or just criticism?

Comment: Android O did not remove the `providers_changed` broadcast, only made it so background apps can't register via app manifest to receive implicit broadcasts not specifically targeting the apps. But the [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) say this restriction can be changed in the app settings, have you tried that? The [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) also say context-based broadcast registrations are still allowed, have you tried registering for the broadcast using `Context.registerReceiver()` instead of the app manifest?

Comment: Update: I tried registering dynamically again, this time using the `LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION` constant, rather than the hard-coded string `android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED`, and it seems to be working (for now).. This is great news.. Although I would still love to know how I might go about removing the restriction directly from the App's settings, as I assume this would be less likely to be killed.. Could you possibly point me in the right direction for how to go about requesting the user to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
Register your `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically (from within your code), instead of from the Manifest.. Also, instead of checking for the hard-coded regex `android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED`, you should use `LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION` (and of course import the `LocationManager`).

**Example:**

```
public void buttonClick(View view) {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Action MATCHES LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION!");
            }
        }
    };

    this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    Log.i(TAG, "RECEIVER HAS BEEN REGISTERED");

}
```

Remember to *unregister* the receiver in your code appropriately, as it will indeed continue running in the background even after the user presses the back-button or home-button. The only time it will stop receiving is if the user kills it from the multitask button, or force stops it.